# Vis.js callback when the network finishes loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, vis.js

I'm using a [vis.js](http://visjs.org/) network that takes in some data and add's said data as nodes within the network.

The only issue is that after the network has been declared (using the nodes and edges specified, which may be a lot) it takes a while for the nodes in the network to render in.

Even when I declare the network like so:

```
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

And then follow it up with making the container visible:

```
$('#BreakdownBox').css('display','inline');
```

It still becomes visible before the nodes have finished buffering, showing a blank canvas until they've rendered in.

**My Question:** How can I only make it visible once it's finished loading the nodes? 
Is there a way to use the [promises.js](https://www.promisejs.org/) with this? Something like:

```
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options).done(function{
    $('#BreakdownBox').css('display','inline');
});
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the end I used the native loading bar to vis.js, using their example code [here](http://visjs.org/examples/network/exampleApplications/loadingBar.html)

It's a little faulty but it's all I needed.

Comment: The page is 404. Yet another example of why StackOverflow should always copy the code instead of linking to the page...

Answer (score 3):

You can refer the example [visjs loading bar](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/exampleApplications/loadingBar.html).

What you need is listening on the "stabilizationIterationsDone" event to hide your progress bar

```
network.once("stabilizationIterationsDone", function() {
   $('#BreakdownBox').css('display','none');

});
```

Comment: This assumes that physics is switched on. This solution doesn't work is physics is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Your code will be executed once and the function will be removed. Since your code is bound to the 'afterDrawing' event instead of the 'stabilizationIterationsDone' event it will be executed even if you have physics disabled.

```
const functionThatDoesWhatYouNeed = () ={ 
    // Your code
    network.off('afterDrawing', functionThatDoesWhatYouNeed)
}
network.on('afterDrawing', functionThatDoesWhatYouNeed)
```

It bounds a function to the 'afterDrawing' event and removes itself so that it does not executed more than once.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be the accepted one.